# How to call the function of a sibling class, from a class within the other sibling class in C#

Tags: c#, function, class, call

I have been assigned to upgrade a home media system by enabling remote control of the room audio system through the internet. As it is a legacy system, I am unable to alter much of the architecture. Below is a simplified form of the program. The system is composed of a few main classes initialized in the Home_Media_System object.

```
class Home_Media_System
{

    Network _networkdata

    Speakers _speakers

    Lights  _lights

    Household_devices household_devices

}

class Speakers
{
    void Play_Audio();
}


class Network
{
    UdpReceiver udpReceiver
    UdpTransmitter udpTransmitter

}


class UdpReceiver
{
    void receive_audio_player_command()
    {
        if(playCommand)
            start_audio();
    }

    void start_audio()
    {
        //How do I call the Play_Audio() function in class Speakers
    }

}

class UdpTransmitter
{
    void send_response();
}
```

My problem is to call the Play_Audio() function after receiving the command in the UdpReceiver class WITHIN the Network class. I hope this clears up the question title, as it was pretty hard to explain in a single sentence.

Note that the main classes are initialized in the Home_Media_System. Right now I am thinking of using double event handlers, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do so.

Comment: This question can't be answered. It depends on the implementation of your software.

Comment: sounds like delegation

Comment: You classes are not public so you may not be able to access these classes outside the main class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some bad hierarchy you have and there is something definitely wrong with design. But just to answer this we can use events/delegates in C# to communicate between siblings via parent. So I will define a event at two places:

In your  `Network` class and in `UdpReceiver` class and raise events when needed

```
public class Network
{
    private UdpReceiver udpReceiver;
    UdpTransmitter udpTransmitter
    public event EventHandler PlayAudioEvent;

    public void Network()
    {
        udpReceiver.PlayAudioEvent += PlayAudioEventHandler;

    }

    void PlayAudioEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PlayAudioEvent != null)
        {
            PlayAudioEvent(this, null);
        }
     }
}

public class UdpReceiver
{
     public event EventHandler PlayAudioEvent;
    void receive_audio_player_command()
    {
        if(playCommand)
            start_audio();
    }

    void start_audio()
    {
        //How do I call the Play_Audio() function in class Speakers
        if (PlayAudioEvent != null)
        {
            PlayAudioEvent(this, null);
        }
    }

}

public class Home_Media_System
{


        public void Home_Media_System()
        {
            _networkdata.PlayAudioEvent +=  PlayAudioEventHandler
        }

        void PlayAudioEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _speakers.PlayAudio();
        }
```

also make all your classes as public/internal and method also as public.

Comment: You are not unsubscribing the events. Isn't that bad?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your classes are private like your methods, to call play audio method you should add public before void, the same role works for all methods, when you make your method public then you have to create instance of you class

```
Speakers speakers= new Speakers();
speakers.Play_Audio();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, however I can't do that as this will be creating a new instance of speakers without the parameters I want. 
I need to access the speakers object initialized in the Home_Media_System.